# Generating integers from a linear combination of integers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Given are some positive integers $t_1, ..., t_n$ such that $\mathrm{gcd}(t_1, ..., t_n) = 1$. Now we create a linear combination of these: $k_1 t_1 + ... + k_n t_n$ where $k_1, ..., k_n$ are nonnegative integers that you can choose to generate different integers.

What is the smallest $N$ such that all integers greater than or equal to $N$ can be generated by the linear combination?

Example: $k_1 3 + k_2 4$ can generate $0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...$. So here $N = 6$ and $k_1 = 2, k_2 = 0$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a famous problem, sometimes called the coin problem of Frobenius.

If $n=2$ the answer to your question is known to be $N = t_1 t_2 - (t_1 + t_2) + 1$.  A proof of this can be found in the answer to this [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8186/).

For three or more integers, there is no known closed-form solution for $N$.  There are some bounds on the values of $N$ in the $n = 3$ case, as well as some algorithms for determining $N$.  For more information and references, see the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) and [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoinProblem.html) pages on the Frobenius coin problem.

Basically, the problem is considered solved when $n = 2$, partially solved (because of the bounds and algorithms) when $n = 3$, and unsolved when $n \geq 4$.

Update: Guy's *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory* says, "The case $n = 3$ was first solved explicitly by Selmer and Beyer, using a continued fraction algorithm."  So I guess the $n=3$ case has been solved.  I suppose you have would have to dig up their paper (it's in the MathWorld references) to see their solution.

Comment: Thanks! I am glad I finally gave up and asked here :-)

Comment: PS: You might want to change the k's to t's to match the question.

Comment: @hakos: [Here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.1978.301.161) is the Selmer/Beyer paper, and here are [two](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.1979.307-308.431) [other](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jnth.1994.1071) papers you might be interested in.