# Error in finding Solution for positive Diophantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

I need to find minimum value of c above which there always exists a non-negative solution for the equation

$$4x + 7y = c$$
 I tried using Diophantine equation but I am not able to find the mistake in my approach, could someone please point out? :

$$4x + 7y = c$$ where $x,y\geq 0$ and $GCD(x,y) = 1$.

$x = 2c$ and $y = -c$ satisfies the above equation.

Now $x_0 = 2c - 7t$ and $y_0 = -c + 4t$ (Diophantine equation solution)

$$2c - 7t \geq 0\implies  t \leq 2c/7$$

Similarly

$$t\geq c/4$$

therefore $2c/7 - c/4 \geq 0$ which gives
$c \geq 28$ but I know the answer for this is $18$.

Comment: Just a language note: "Diophantine equation" is not a technique, it is a class of problems.

Comment: I think it should $\frac{2c}7-\frac c4\ge 1$ Also, $c=4x+7y\ge 4+7=11?$

Comment: But you really just need an integer between $c/4$ and $2c/7$, which can happen if their difference is between $0$ and $1$, too. It's certainly the case that for $c\geq 28$ you can always find a solution.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes there always exist a solution for c>= 28 but it looks it also holds for c>= 18, so does this approach not necessarily give the minimum value or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @rishabh $18$ is not right if you want $x,y$ positive. $18$ is only right if you allow $x$ or $y$ to be zero, also. For example, there is no positive solution to $4x+7y=21$. Indeed, there is no positive solution even to $4x+7y=28$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews zero is also allowed, i should have written non-negative

Comment: The standard argument about the largest number not representable is **not** manipulation of the inequalities for $t$. Those are too coarse: a gap of $1$ is sufficient but not necessary. The argument above can be supplemented by checking numbers $27, 26,\dots$. Or one can use a different proof that does not come from the inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma: If $x,y$ are real and $y-x>1$ then there is an integer $t$ such that $x<t<y$.

I'll let you prove that.

So your argument actually shows that if $c\geq 29$ then $2c/7-c/4>1$, and therefore there is a solution to $4x+7y=c$ with $x,y>0$. Then $4(x-1)+7(y-1)=c-11$ has a solution, and hence if $c\geq 18$, solve $4x_0+7y_0=c+11$ with $x_0,y_0>0$, and then $x=x_0-1$ and $u=y_0-1$ is a non-negative solution to $4x+7y=c$.

Note, this does not prove that $18$ is the smallest - to do that, you have to show that $4x+7y=17$ has no non-negative solution, or, equivalently, that there is no integer in the range $[17/4,34/7]$.

This also shows you how you get the coin problem result. If $a,b$ are relatively prime, first show that if $c\geq ab+1$, then $ax+by = c$ has a positive solution. But that means that if $c\geq ab+1 - a - b = (a-1)(b-1)$ then $ax+by=c$ has a non-negative solution.

And then, again, you need to show that there is no solution when $c=(a-1)(b-1)-1=ab-a-b$. But that can be done as follows. 
We can quickly show that $$a(b-1) + b(-1)= ab-b-a$$ so any integer solution to $ax+by=ab-b-a$ must be of the form:
$$x_0 = b-1 - bt, y_0=-1+at$$

But if $x_0=b-1-bt\geq 0$ then $t<1$ and if $y_0=-1+at\geq 0$ then $t>0$. There is no integer between $0$ and $1$, so there is no non-negative solution to $ax+by= ab-a-b$.

Comment: shouldn't it be 4(x-1) + 7(y-1) = c - 11?

Comment: yes I think its a typo, you wrote 7(x-1) instead of 7(y-1).

Comment: (Fixed, and added the last step to the general answer.) @rishabh

Comment: Thanks a lot. also a small typo in: "that there is no integer in the range [17/4,34/4]" must be [17/4,34/7] while proving that 18 is the smallest number.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that $x=2c, y=-c$ is a solution, but then when you say $x_0=2c-7t, y_0=-c+4t$ you are adding in the same number of $4$'s that you remove $7$'s

The [coin problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) shows the maximum unrepresentable number is $4\cdot 7 -4-7=17$

Comment: Actually I am reading  "Elementary Number Theory" by David Burton and it has a theorem which stated the solution (if it exists) for ax + by = c  is x = x0 + (b/d) t, y = y0 - (a/d) t, given x0 and y0 is any particular solution of the equation. Am I missing here something?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple proof. By the theorem you quote in your comment to Ross's answer, we know that all of the solutions of $\rm\:N\ =\ 4\ X + 7\ Y\:$ arise from adding or subtracting multiples of $\rm\:(-7,4)\:$ to any particular solution $\rm\:(X,Y).\:$ Thus we may *normalize* any representation $\rm\ N\ =\ 4\ X + 7\ Y\ $  so  that $\rm\ 0 \le X \le 6,\: $ by adding some integral multiple of $\rm\ (-7,4)\ $ to $\rm\:(X,Y),\:$ i.e. by choosing $\rm\,K\,$ so that $\rm\:(X,Y)+K(-7,4)\, =\, (X\!-\!7K,\,Y\!+\!4K)\:$ has $\rm\:0\le X\!-\!7K \le 6.\:$  Then we observe

**Lemma** $\rm\ \  N \,=\, 4\, X\! + 7\, Y\ $ for some integers  $\rm\ X,Y \ge 0\, $
$\iff$ its normalization has $\rm\: Y \ge 0\:$.

**Proof** $\rm\ \ (\Rightarrow)\ \ $ If $\rm\ X,Y \ge 0\ $ then normalization adds $\rm\:(-7,4)\:$ zero or more times (in order to get $\rm\:0 \le X \le 6),\ $ and this preserves the condition $\rm\: Y \ge 0\:.\ $ $\ (\Leftarrow)\ \ $ Conversely if the normalization has $\rm\: Y < 0\:,\ $ then $\rm\:N\:$ has no 
representation with $\rm\ X, Y \ge 0\:,\: $ because to shift $\rm\: Y > 0\: $ 
requires adding $\rm\ (-7,4)\ $ at least once, which (since $\rm\:0\le X\le 6),\:$ shifts $\rm\: X < 0\:.\ $ **QED**

Finally, since $\rm\ 4\,X\! + 7\, Y\ $  is increasing in both $\rm\: X,Y\:,\ $
it is clear that the largest non-representable number $\rm\: N\:$ has normalization
$\rm\: (X,Y)\ =\ (6,-1)\:,\: $ corresponding to $\rm\ N\ =\ 4\cdot 6 - 1\cdot 7\, =\, 17.$

Precisely the [same argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21032/23500) works also for the general case. This classic problem is known by a great variety of aliases, e.g. postage stamp problem, Sylvester/Frobenius problem, Diophantine problem of Frobenius, Frobenius conductor, money changing, coin changing, change making problems. See also: h-basis and asymptotic bases in additive number theory, integer programming algorithms and Gomory cuts, knapsack problems and greedy algorithms, etc.

Comment: Could you please explain this point "since  4X+7Y  is increasing in both X,Y,  it is clear that the largest non-representable number N has normalization (X,Y) = (6,−1)".I can't understand how to find normalization.