# $ax+by$ when a,b are relatively prime and $x,y\geq 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was solving below question in Automaton theory

$$L=\{a^m|m=3x+5y; x,y\geq 0\}$$ then the number of states in minimal dfa is?

What I observed is that $3x+5y$ generated every number after $7(8,9,10,11,12 ------)$
and is there any property that I can use to see why this is so or at least could someone provide source from which I can learn more about this

I put the title "$ax+by$ when a,b are relatively prime" because I thought this might be due to 3,5 are relatively prime (correct me if I am wrong) , I don't know anything about this except that it might be related to number theory.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Check out [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69961/11619). Robjohn's answer in particular gets to the point. I refrain from voting to close this as a duplicate, because I don't know if that answers the question about *a minimal dfa* (whathever that is). Anyway, you were right in that the gcd-condition is crucial. I'm sad to say the answerers got it wrong given that they failed to take notice of the condition $x,y\ge0$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you so much. Yes,this is what I was looking for you may close this question

Comment: If $k=5x+3y$ then $k+3=5x+3(y+1)$. So $8=5\cdot 1+3\cdot 1, 9=5\cdot 0+3\cdot 3, 10=5\cdot 2+3\cdot 0$ means that every integer greater than $7$ can be written as $5x+3y.$

Comment: This is a famous question, sometimes known as the Coin problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Thanks.Very interesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking about [The coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem), which is reasonably well-studied. I encourage you to check out the Wiki article I linked there.

The "Frobenius" of a set of numbers is the smallest one that you can't make as a sum of the numbers in the set - in a land with 3-penny pieces and 5-penny pieces only, you can't pay 7 pennies, but you can pay any amount larger than that.

The Frobenius of a two number set $\{m,n\}$ is given by the formula $F=mn-m-n$. In this case, $15-3-5=7$.

How do we know that every number greater than $7$ is accessible? Here's a not-too-technical proof: If you have enough $5$'s, you can "add $1$" to your total by getting rid of a $5$ and replacing it with two $3$'s $(1=-5+6)$. If you have enough $3$'s, you can add $1$ to your total by getting rid of three of them and replacing them with two $5$'s $(1=-9+10)$.

Thus, if you have at least one $5$ or at least three $3$'s in your sum expressing $n$, then you can also express $n+1$. For numbers over $7$, there is always at least one $5$ or at least three $3$'s in its composition. This is particularly clear for numbers $\ge 15$, and it can be seen with a little more work, for the numbers $8,9,\ldots,14$.

Comment: Thanks,especially for not-too-technical proof :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of [Bezout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), which implies that for $a,b$ relatively prime, there are $\hat{x},\hat{y}$ such that $a\hat{x} + b\hat{y} = 1$. Then for any integer $n$, we choose $x = n\hat{x}$ and $y= n\hat{y}$ and we have $ax + by = n$.

These $x,y$ aren't necessarily $\geq 0$. However, we can determine a lower bound for which we can find a solution with $x,y  \geq 0$. We can always adjust a solution by changing $x$ to $x \pm b$ and $y$ to $y \mp a$. If we can guarantee that some value $x = n\hat{x} \pm mb$ satisfies $0 \leq x\leq \frac{n}{a}$, the corresponding value of $y$ will be nonnegative. This is possible if $\frac{n}{a} \geq b-1$. Similarly, we can guarantee a nonnegative solution if $\frac{n}{b} \geq a -1$. So If $n \geq ab - \max\{a,b\}$, we can guarantee a nonnegative solution.

Clearly this isn't always the best lower bound; in your case this gives $n \geq 10$, while you've showed it possible for $n \geq 8$.

EDIT: As Jyrki Lahtonen pointed out in the comments, robjohn does a much better job doing what I was trying to do (and he actually gets the best bound) in his answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69961/determine-the-set-of-a-sum-of-numbers). For an answer without Bezout's identity, see my other answer to this question, which gets the best bound.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easier way to see this:

Let $b>a$. Consider the sequences of numbers:

- $0$, $a$, $2a$, $3a$, $\dots$
- $b$, $b+a$, $b+2a$, $b+3a$, $\dots$
- $2b$, $2b+a$, $2b+2a$, $2b+3a$, $\dots$
- $\dots$
- $(a-1)b$, $(a-1)b+a$, $(a-1)b+2a$, $(a-1)b+3a$, $\dots$

The first row contains integers congruent to $0 \mod a$, the second row congruent to $b \mod a$, etc. Since $b$ and $a$ are coprime, each row represents a different modulus, and the $a$ rows exhaust all moduli $\mod a$.

Now every number has some modulus $\mod a$, and a number appears in some row iff it is $\geq$ the lowest number in that row. Thus all numbers $\geq (a-1)b$ appear somewhere, as I showed in my other answer.

We can now improve on this bound. The number $(a-1)b -a = ab - b - a$ does not appear because it has modulus $-b$ and is less than $(a-1)b$. However, $(a-1)b-a > (a-1)b - b = (a-2)b$, so all numbers greater than $ab - b - a$ with modulus other than $-b$ appear. Since the next number with modulus $-b$ is $(a-1)b$, which appears, all numbers greater than $ab - b - a$ appear.

So if $n \geq ab - b - a + 1 = (a-1)(b-1)$, we can write $n = ax + by$ with $x,y \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly magic proof.

> **Lemma:** If $a,b$ are relatively prime positive integers, then for any integer $n$ there is solution to $ax+by=n$ with $x,y$ integers and $0\leq x\leq b-1.$ (So, possibly with $y<0$.)

**Proof:** We know we can find integers $x_0,y_0$ so that $ax_0+by_0=n.$

By the division algorithm, we can find integers $q,r$ so that $x_0=bq+r$ with $0\leq r\leq b-1.$ Then:

$$ar + b(y_0+aq)=a(r+bq)+by=ax_0+by_0=n$$

So there is a solution $(x,y)=(r,y_0+aq)$ with $0\leq r=x\leq b-1.$

> **Theorem:** If $a,b$ are relatively prime positive integers, then for each integer $n$, there is a non-negative integer solution to at least on of the equations $ax+by=n$ or to $ax+by=ab-a-b-n.$

(There is a stronger statement, which is that for each $n$, exactly one of those two equations has a solution.)

In your case, this would mean for each $n$, one of $3x+5y=n$ and $3x+5y=7-n$ has a non-negative solution.

**Proof**: Solve $ax_0+by_0=n$ with integers $x_0,y_0$ and $0\leq x_0\leq b-1.$

If $y_0\geq 0$ we are done.

If $y_0<0$ then:

$$ab-a-b-n = a(b-1)-a-b-(ax_0+by_0)=a(b-1-x_0)+b(-1-y_0)$$

Since $0\leq b-1-x_0$ and $0\leq -1-y_0$ we either have non-negative solutions ot $ax+by=n$ or to $ax+b=ab-a-b-n.$

Now, if $N>ab-a-b$, or $N\geq (a-1)(b-1)$, then there there can't be non-negative solutions to $ax+by=ab-a-b-N<0,$ so there must be a solution to $ax+by=N.$

---

The stronger version of the theorem is that, for any integer $n,$ *exactly* one of the equations $$\begin{align}ax+by&=n\\ax+by&=ab-a-b-n\end{align}$$

has a non-negative solution.

You can show this by showing that $ax+by=ab-a-b$ has no non-negative integer solution $(x,y)$. This is because if both the equations have non-negative solutions, you could add them to get a non-negative solution for $ax+by=ab-a-b.$

If $ax+by=ab-a-b$ then $a(x+1)+b(y+1)=ab.$ So $b\mid a(x+1)$ and $a\mid b(y+1).$ But since $a,b$ are relatively prime, we get that $b\mid x+1$ and $a\mid y+1.$

But if $x,y\geq 0,$ $x\geq b-1$ and $y\geq a-1$, and thus $ax+by\geq 2ab-a-b>ab-a-b,$ reaching a contradiction.

This lets us count the number of non-negative integers $n$ for which there is no solution:

$$\frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{2}$$

---

A generating function approach is to ask which coefficients of:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^a}\frac{1}{1-x^b}$$

are $0$. We can write:

$$f(x)=\frac{\left(1+x^a+\cdots+x^{a(b-1)}\right)\left(1+x^b+\cdots+x^{b(a-1)}\right)}{\left(1-x^{ab}\right)^2}$$

The denominator contributes only additional multiples of $ab$ to the exponents, and since we know that all sufficiently large values have a solution, this means that the exponents in the numerator must cover all the values modulo $ab$, which means that they must all have coefficient $1$. If $S$ is the set of positive values $n$ for which no $ax+by=n$, we can write the numerator as:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{ab-1} x^k -\left(1-x^{ab}\right)\sum_{k\in S} x^k$$

So, one way to enumerate the numbers in $S$ is:

$$S=\{ax+by-ab\mid 1\leq x\leq b-1, 1\leq y\leq a-1, ax+by\geq ab\}$$

We can see exactly half the pairs $x,y$ have $ax+by>ab$ beacuse if $ax+by>ab$ then $a(b-x)+b(a-y)=2ab-(ax+by)<ab$. (Not that there is no $x,y$ with $ax+by=ab$ since $x\leq b-1,y\leq a-1$.) So again we get that there must be $\frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{2}$ elements of $S$.

We can count $S$ another way and get the result: $$\sum_{x=1}^{b-1}\left\lfloor \frac{ax}{b}\right\rfloor=\frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{2}.$$

Now, our generating function is:
$$f(x)=\frac{\frac{x^{ab}-1}{x-1}+\left(x^{ab}-1\right)\sum_{k\in S} x^k}{(1-x^{ab})^2}=\frac{1}{(x-1)(x^{ab}-1)}-\frac{\sum_{k\in S} x^k}{1-x^{ab}}$$

The coefficient of $x^n$ in the left part is $1+\left\lfloor \frac{n}{ab}\right\rfloor$ the coefficient of $x^n$ in the right term is $1$ if $n$ is congruent to some $s\in S$ modulo $ab$. So the number of non-negative solutions to $ax+by=n$ is:

$$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{ab}\right\rfloor+\begin{cases}0&n\equiv s\pmod{ab} \text{ for some } s\in S\\
1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

---

The case when $b=2a-1$ gives us an easy way to list $S$:

$$S=\{i+aj\mid 1\leq i\leq a-1, 0\leq j\leq 2(a-i-1)\}$$

This gives, for $a=3,b=5$ that $S=\{1,4,7,2\}.$

For $a=5,b=9$ this gives $S=\{1,6,11,16,21,26,31,2,7,12,17,22,3,8,13,4\}.$

More generally, if $a<b$, we can list, for each $i\in\{1,\dots,a-1\}$ the values $i+aj$ until we get one divisible by $b$.

For example, $a=3,b=10$ gives:

$$\{1,1+3,1+6,2,2+3,2+6,2+9,2+12,2+15\}$$

If $a<b$ and $ax\equiv -1\pmod {b}$ for $1\leq x\leq b-1$, then you get:

$$S=\{i+bj\mid 1\leq i\leq a-1, 0\leq j<(ix\bmod b)\}$$

If $b=ax+1$ then $0\leq j< xi$. For example, when $a=4,b=13,x=3,$ you get:
$$S=\{1,1+4,1+4\cdot 2,\\
2,2+4,\dots,2+4\cdot 5,\\
3,3+4,\dots,3+4\cdot 8\}$$

If $b=ay-1$ for $y>1,$ then $x = b-y$ and for $i$ you get $0\leq j< b-iy.$

This formula also lets you count $S$ again, since the number of elements for $i$ is $ix\bmod b$ and the number of elements for $a-i$ is $(a-i)x\bmod b$, and $xi+(a-i)x=ax\equiv -1\pmod b$. Since $(xi\bmod b)+((a-i)x\bmod b)\leq 2b-2$, we must have the total for these $i,a-i$ to be $b-1$, so the average over all $i$ must be $\frac{b-1}{2}$, and we get, again, that $|S|=(a-1)\frac{(b-1)}{2}.$

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21032/242) for a geometric view of the lemma.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as you write, since $3$ and $5$ are relatively prime, there are integers $x, y$ such that $3x + 5y = 1$ (this is Bézout's identity).

In particular, this means that, to generate an integer $k$, you have the pair $(kx, ky)$, so that

$$3kx + 5ky = k.$$

Comment: but for x,y >= 0 there is no solution for 3x+5y=1