# Linear combination of natural numbers with positive coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I'm searching for a reference for the following result, so as to avoid writing a full proof in a paper.  Alternatively, if a one-liner exists, I'd be glad to know it!

**Theorem:** Let $a, b$ be two positive integers.  Then there is a finite set $N$ of positive integers smaller than $\mbox{lcm}(a, b)$ such that:
$$\{k_1a + k_2b \mid k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb{N}\} = \{\mbox{lcm}(a, b) + k\times\gcd(a, b) \mid k \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup N.$$

I'm also interested in its generalization to any number of integers: Say a set of integers is a *linear set with $n$ periods* if it can be written as:
$$\{c_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n k_i \times c_i \mid k_i \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$
Then:

**Theorem:** Any linear set is the union of a finite set and a linear set with *one* period.

Thanks!

Comment: @Byron: Thanks for the bounty.  I'm indeed searching for a reference.

Comment: @Jyrki: Kiitos!  Pointing out numerical semigroups helped me find  Rosales and Garcia-Sanchez's book, and I thus phrased: "A linear set of dimension~1 can be expressed as the union of a finite set and a linear set with \emph{one} period: One possible way to see that is to consider $C = c_0 + P^*$ for some finite set $P$, and recall that $P^*$ is a numerical semigroup multiplied by a constant $k$ \cite[Proposition~2.2]{rosales-garcia09}, and thus is expressible as $k \times (\mathbb{N} \setminus F)$, with $F \subset \mathbb{N}$ a finite set."  Would you please turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer as per your request. Deleting the now obsolete comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wikipedia article on [numerical semigroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_semigroup) contains several references that may help you. I also recommend [an answer by Robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69961/determine-the-set-of-a-sum-of-numbers/70040#70040) to another question here in MSE. The question was about a particular case, but Robjohn covered the general case of a numerical semigroup generated by two coprime numbers very nicely.

Comment: I'll just add that numerical semigroups are also mentioned in [several other posts on MSE](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22numerical+semigroups%22+site:math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks for the extra link, @Martin. It didn't feel right to receive a generous bounty for a Wikilink. It still doesn't. But it is the OP's call.

Answer (score 7):

Some variant of the following result is proved in most books in elementary number theory.

**Theorem:** Let $a$ and $b$ be *relatively prime* positive integers.  If $c >ab$, then there exist positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=c$.

The proof is not difficult. It is not quite a one-liner, largely because I am not a man of few words.

There are *integers* $x_0,y_0$, such that $ax_0+by_0=c$.  Consequently, all integer solutions of the equation $ax+by=c$  have the shape $x=x_0+bt$, $y=y_0-at$, where $t$ ranges over the integers.  To produce a positive solution, we want to find $t$ such that $x>0$ and $y>0$.

So we need $y_0-at >0$, $x_0+bt>0$, or equivalently 
$$-\frac{x_0}{b}<t <\frac{y_0}{a}.$$
The interval  $(-x_0/b,y_0/a)$ has width $y_0/a+x_0/b$. which simplifies to $(ax_0+by_0)/ab$, that is, $c/ab$.  If $c/ab>1$, then the interval is guaranteed to contain an integer $t$, and we are finished.

If $a$ and $b$ are not relatively prime, let $d=\gcd(a,b)$, and let $a=da'$, $b=db'$. Let $c$ be a multiple of $d$, say $c=c'd$. Then if $c'>a'b'$, $c$ is representable as a positive linear combination of $a$ and $b$.  Equivalently, every multiple $c$ of $d$ which is greater than $ab/d$ is a positive linear combination of $a$ and $b$.

In particular, the $\text{lcm}(a,b)$ term in your expression puts us *past* the numbers that do not have a positive representation. The bound $ab/d$ is quite sharp.

The generalization to "many periods" is straightforward. Getting *sharp* bounds on the smallest number $m$ such that all $c$ that satisfy the necessary divisibility condition are representable may not be easy.

Answer (score 5):

Let $c_1,\dots,c_n$ be positive integers and set
$a=\gcd(c_1,\dots,c_n)$. By [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#Generalizations), we can write $a=\sum_{i=1}^n z_i c_i$
for *integers* $z_i$.

Letting  $c=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i$, every multiple $N$ of $a$ can be written as $N=qc+ra$ where $q,r$ are  integers
with $0\leq r<c/a$.

If $N$ is large enough, in particular if
$N\geq c+\max_i |z_i|c^2/a$, then the coefficients in
$N=\sum_{i=1}^n (q+z_ir) c_i$ are all non-negative.
That is, every *large* multiple of $a$ can be written $N=\sum_{i=1}^n k_i c_i$
for non-negative integers $k_i$.

That is, $$\{c_0 + k a\mid k \in \mathbb{N}\}\setminus \{c_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n k_i  c_i \mid k_i \in \mathbb{N}\}$$ is a finite set.