# Prove that a group of size $\ge18$ people can be assembled from groups of 4 and 7

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

How can I prove that a group of size $\ge18$ can be assembled from groups of $4$ and $7$ using the well ordering principle?

Well-ordering principle: Every nonempty subset $T$ of $N$ has a least
element. That is, there is an $m ∈ T$ such that $m ≤ n$ for all $n ∈ T$.

I have the following unorganized thoughts: I can only prove this by induction not Well Ordering Principle so please let me know how to do that!

Proposition: 
$P(n)$: If n $\ge18$, there is a group of people of size $n$ made from groups of $4$ or $7$.

$P(0)$: is vacuously true

Inductive step: assume $P(0)...P(n)$ is true. Then $P(n+1)$ must also be true. 
I don't know how to write this part:

---Unorganized thoughts
The rules that I have come up with is:

1. If the size is $\ge 5$ groups of $4$, then you replace by $3$ groups of $7$.
2. If the number cannot be represented in multiples of $5$ groups of $4$, replace one of the groups of $7$ by $2$ groups of $4$
3. Repeat as needed until you get the requested number, which is now made up of groups of $4$ and $7$.

How do I write that as a proof? These are unorganized thoughts.

Please write your steps in detailed order so I can follow. I'm not very proficient in math symbolism so please explain symbols if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Am I the only one who finds this question extremely unclear? "$18$ or more"??? Why don't you simply take $3$ groups of $7$ people (one out of many possible examples)? Do you mean that you want to prove this for every possible integer value greater than or equal to $18$?

Comment: Yes for every possible integer value $\ge 18$

Comment: Look up *numerical semigroups* from Wikipedia (*Frobenius coin problem* is another good buzzword) or, just read [robjohn's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/70040/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Same principle, but labeling it as a duplicate goes to far in my view.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the *well ordering principle* is, but here is how I would prove this:

- $A_{18} = \{4,7,7\}$
- $A_{19} = \{4,4,4,7\}$
- $A_{20} = \{4,4,4,4,4\}$
- $A_{21} = \{7,7,7\}$
- $A_{n}  = \{4\} \cup A_{n-4}$

Comment: "using well ordering principle" can be read as "by induction". So your interpretation of it is correct, as well as your answer.

Comment: @drhab: Yeah, I see the additional tags now (they weren't there before). I could probably write a more formal proof by induction, but will wait to see if OP can't figure it out at this point. Thanks.

Comment: @barakmanos I have included a definition of the well ordering principle in the main question. Can you please rephrase your proof according to the well ordering principle? Thanks!