# Alternative derivation of the second Frobenius number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $a,b$ be integers with $\gcd(a,b)=1$. What is then the largest integer $N$ which cannot be written as a linear combination with non-negative integer coefficients of $a$ and $b$?

A few days ago, I came up with the following elementary proof.

Because $\gcd(a,b)=1$, the diophantine equation
$$ax+by=N$$
has infinitely many solutions if $x,y$ are allowed to be negative. The solutions can be written parametrically as
$$x=Nx_0-bt, \ y=Ny_0+at$$ 
with $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $(x_0,y_0)$ satisfying $ax_0+by_0=1$.

The integers $x$ and $y$ must be nonnegative for an attainable number, which we may write as $x,y>-1$, which is equivalent to
$$-1/a-Ny_0/a<t<Nx_0/b+1/b$$
The largest $N$ for which this fails satisfies
$$(Nx_0/b+1/b)-(-1/a-Ny_0/a)=1$$
whence
$$N=ab-(a+b)$$
as desired.

However, I recall reading a much more complicated proof based on complete residue systems in a book on number theory some years ago. Does this alternative proof seem familiar to anyone?

Comment: @T.Bongers Wait a little, I'll change my question. I'm actually looking for an alternative proof. I came up with the proof above a few days ago, but also recall reading some much more elaborate proof in a number theory book a while ago. Could this be a valid question?

Comment: I have gotten into the habit of referring askers to [this answer by Robjohn](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/70040/11619). Not sure how well it compares. Anyway, there are more links to related threads there.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I assume you are referring to his theorem 1. The proof he gives (although the statement is different), is basically the proof I have above.