# The Postage Stamp Problem Using Money and seeing if possible without change

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

Here is the problem:

> Suppose you have only 13-dollar and 7-dollar bills.
>
> a) You need to pay someone 71 dollars. Is this possible without receiving change? If so, show how to do it. If not, explain why it is impossible.
>
> b) Suppose you need to pay someone 75 dollars. Is it possible? If so, show how to do it. If not, explain why it is impossible.

I have been trying to do this problem but I get stuck after I write the equation $13x+7y=71$. I know that the $\gcd(13,7)=1$ and $1$ divides $71$, so there must be infinite solutions, but I don't know how to actually solve the equation and limit the answer to no change.

Comment: There are only infinitely many solutions if you allow your variables to be negative (which doesn't make sense with dollar bills).

Comment: There can't be infinite solutions, right? You just have to try $x = (0,1,2,3,4,5)$ because you can't receive any kind of change, in which case you get no possibilities. You might have to include receiving change in $7$ and $13$ dollar bills.

Comment: Well 2x7 - 1x13 = 1.  So 5x13 = 65 = 71 - 6.  So 5x13 + 7 = 72 = 71 + 1.  So (5*13 + 7) - (2x7  -13) = 72 - 1 = 72.  So 6x13 - 7 = 71.  But you don't want  that because they aren't bot positive.  We need to increase the number of 7 bills and decrease the number of 13 bills so we need (6 -b)x13 +(a -1)x7 = 71.  What a and b will work?  Solving we get 7a = 13b.  so we need 6-b $\ge$ 0.  and $13b/7 - 1 >0$.  Is that possible?

Comment: See [robjohn's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/70040/11619) for the case of 2 bills with arbitrary (integer) dollar values. Note that you obviously can only get multiples of their gcd, so in the 2 bill variant you can just factor that out. With 3 or more different value bills, the question is more difficult.

Comment: Anyway, the umbrella concept here is that of [a numerical semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_semigroup) aka Frobenius coin problem. I think the postage stamp problem is a bit different. IIRC there we often also place a constraint on the number of stamps you can fit on the envelope.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note:

1) There are integer solutions to $Kx + My = Z$ if and only $\gcd(K,M) | Z$.  *BUT* these solutions might have negative integer values.

$\gcd(13,7) = 1$ and $1$ divides everything so a) and b) have solutions but they may b be negative solutions which are not acceptable for monetary transactions.

2) To determine possible solutions for $Kx + My = Z = Z'\gcd(K,M)$:

It suffices the assume $\gcd(M,) = 1$ as $Kx + My = Z'\gcd(K,M)$ will have the exact same  solutions as $\frac {K}{\gcd(K,M)}x + \frac{M}{\gcd(K,M)} = Z'$.

It also suffices to assume $K \not \mid Z$ so as $K\frac{Z}K + M*0 = Z$ would be a trivial and obvious solution.

So we will assume if $Kx + My = Z$ then $x \ne 0$ and $y \ne 0$.

If $Kx + My = Z$ is a solution so is $K(x \pm Mj) + M(y \mp Kj) = Z$.

If $Kx + My =Z$ and $Kx' + My' = Z$ are two solutions then $Kx = Z - My$ so $My \equiv Z \mod K$. Likewise $My' \equiv Z \equiv My \mod K$.  As $\gcd(M,K) = 1$ it follows $y \equiv y' \mod K$.

And obviously we can do the same for $x$.  $x \equiv x' \mod M$ for the exact same reasons.

So $K(x \pm Mj) + M(y \mp Kj) = Z$ are the only solutions and we can find these solutions by solving $My \equiv Z \mod K$ and $Kx \equiv Z \mod M$.

So for example:

a) $7a + 13b = 71$ will have solution when $13b \equiv 71 \mod 7$ so $-b \equiv 1 \mod 7$ so $b \equiv -1 \mod 7$. So $b = -1$ and $7a -13 = 71 \implies a=12$ will be a solution.

$7*12 + 13(-1) = 71$ is a solution.  But it is not an acceptable non-negative solution.

b) $7a + 13b = 75$ will have a solution when $13b \equiv 75 \mod7$ so $-b \equiv 5 \mod 7$ so $b \equiv -5 \mod 7$.   So $b = -5$ and $7a - 13*5 = 75 \implies $a = 20$ will be a solution.

$20*7 - 5*13 = 75$ is a solution but not positive.

3) Finding positive solutions (if any).

If $K(u+Mj) + M(w- Kj) = Z$ are sets of solutions.  $u + Mj \ge 0$ if $j \ge -u/M$.  $w - Kj \ge 0$ if $j \le w/K$.  If there exists $-u/M \le j \le w/K$ then there will be all positive solutions for each possible $j$.  Otherwise there will not be.

So for a)

$7*12 - 13*1 = 71$. We want $7(12 - 13j) + 13(-1 + 7j)= 71$ and we want $1/7 \le j \le 12/13$.  There are no such $j$ and so no positive solutions.

So for b)

We want $7(20 - 13k) + 13(-5 + 7k) = 71$.  So we want $5/7 \le k \le 20/13$.  There is exactly one such $k$ ($k = 1$) so the only positive solution is:

$7(20 - 13) + 13(-5 + 7) = 7*7 + 13*2 = 71$.

Answer (score 0):

a)
You have $71 = 10\cdot 7 + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ so if you try to pay $71$ with $7$-s you'll end up with $1$ to pay. Let's see if $13$-s help.
$13 = 7+6 = 2\cdot 7-1 \equiv 6 \equiv -1 \pmod 7$, so you would need to pay $6$ times $13$ to get a remainder of $1$:
$$6\cdot 13 = 78 = 11\cdot 7+1 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$$
– but that exceeds the value to be paid. You can't pay $71$ with bills of $7$ and $13$ only.

b)
OTOH $75 = 11\cdot 7 - 2 \equiv -2 \pmod 7$, so $2\cdot 13$ should suffice. Let's check:
$2\cdot 13=26$ and $75-26 = 49 = 7\cdot 7$ — yes, you can pay $75$ with seven bills of $7$ and two of $13$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose either $71$ or $75$ can be made up with $n$ bills, in some combination of $7$ and $13$.  Then $6 \leq n \leq 10$ (since $5\times13=65 < 71$ and $11\times7=77 > 75$).

Since $7=(1\times6)+1$ and $13=(2\times6)+1$, we must have, for some integer $m$:
$$\text{Sum of n bills} = 6m+n$$

a) Then we require $71=6m+n$ with $6\leq n\leq10$, which implies $61\leq6m\leq65$. But this is impossible, so $71$ cannot be made up.

b) We require $75=6m+n$ with $6\leq n\leq10$, which implies $65\leq 6m\leq69$ and is solved by $m=11$ and $n=9$. Hence $75$ can be made up using 2 13-dollar bills (because $m-n=11-9=2$ and therefore 7 7-dollar bills.