# prove that for $n\geq 8$ exist $p,q\epsilon\mathbb{N}$ so that $n=5p +3q$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I ve been asked to prove that for $n\geq 8$  exist $p,q\in \mathbb{N}_0$ so that $n=5p +3q$ anyone who could help and explain too?

Comment: You only need to verify that the claim holds for $n=8,9,10$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527496/divisible-by-multiple-numbers-induction

Comment: In particular see [Robjohn's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/70040/11619) for an elementary derivation of the more general result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base of induction $n=8,9,10$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
8 &=5\cdot 1+3\cdot 1\\
9 &=5\cdot 0+3\cdot 1\\
10 &=5\cdot 2+3\cdot 0
\end{eqnarray*}

Induction step $n\to n+3$. By induction hypothetis there are $p,q$ such that $n=5p+3q$. Then:

$$ n+3 = 5p+3q+3 = 5p'+3q'$$ where $q' = q+1$ and $p'=p$.