# The sums of $3$ and $8$ must give a number greater than $13$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove every natural number greater than $13$ can be express as sum of $3$ and $8$ (regardless of order)

Comment: What?  $3+8 = 11$ so from where I sit only $11$ can be expressed as a sum of $3$ and $8$.

Comment: I think he means a linear combination.  Perhaps like 20 = 4*3 + 1*8.

Comment: Should I assume you mean that ever natural number greater than $13$ can be written as $3n + 8m$ for $n,m \in \mathbb N$ (including $0$)?

Comment: "I think he means a linear combination. " It that is what the OP meant he should have made a *bit* of effort to be clearer.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/70040) may answer your question. There, it shows that any number greater than or equal to $(3-1)(8-1)=14$ can be written as a non-negative linear combination of $3$ and $8$.

Comment: exactly, 3n + 8n

Comment: just sshow you can get 14 15 and 16

Comment: @hunter: that is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a well-known Euclidean algorithm,  you will get

$$3m+8n=k$$

$$m = 8 z + 3 k, ~n = -3 z - k, ~  z\in\mathbb Z$$

Then, we need

$$\begin{cases} 8z+3k ≥0 \\-3z-k≥0\\ k>13\end{cases}$$

Finally, we have

$$k>13,  ~ \frac{3k}{8}≥z≥\frac k3$$

For $k>13$, there always exist an integer $z$, such that  $\frac{3k}{8}≥z≥\frac k3$ holds.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.

Comment: @BillDubuque How do you find that these problems are dupe?  Sometimes I can't find it when I search.  Thus, my work becomes meaningless.

Comment: By searching on keywords, e.g. frobenius or coin problem etc.

Answer (score 0):

First prove this for $14,15,16$ because they are the first numbers greater than $13$.

$14=3+3+8$, $15=3+3+3+3+3$, $16 = 8+8$.

Now, if you add $3$ to each of these, you get

$17 = 3+3+3+8$, $18=3+3+3+3+3+3$, $19=8+8+3$

keep going, adding $3$, and you get

$20 = 3+3+3+3+8$, $21=3+3+3+3+3+3+3$, $22=8+8+3+3$

You can clearly see from these examples that all numbers greater than $13$ can be expressed as the sum of $3$s and $8$ because we can just keep adding $3$ to our original trio to get all the numbers.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.