# Define what values of 'n' are impossible to obtain from 3x + 7y = n for positive integers (x,y)

Tags: number-theory

Define what values  of 'n' are impossible to obtain from 3x + 7y = n for positive integers (x,y)

The list I have currently is 1,2,4,5,8,11, which goes for n: 0-20.

I don't quite see a pattern in this. This problem comes from a Stanford Math camp (saw this on Reddit with no answers).

Comment: Can you give a link to where you saw it on reddit?

Comment: Cf. [Frobenius coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Note in this question $x,y>0$ unlike the Frobenius problem where $x,y \ge 0.$

Comment: This is also a duplicate of [Determine the Set of a Sum of Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69961/determine-the-set-of-a-sum-of-numbers).