# basic number theory question (gcd)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Largest integer that can’t be represented as a non-negative linear combination of $m, n = mn - m - n$? Why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66963/largest-integer-that-cant-be-represented-as-a-non-negative-linear-combination-o)

Q: Suppose $u$ and $v$ are positive integers, and $k$ a number such that $\gcd(u, v)$ divides $k$.  If $k > uv - u - v$, show that there are nonnegative integers $x$ and $y$ so that $k = ux + vy$.

I know that there are integers $x$ and $y$ so that $k = ux + vy$ (since $\gcd$ can be expressed this way, and $k$ is a multiple of $\gcd$), but I'm not sure how to use given condition to prove that nonnegative $x$, $y$ exist.

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: sorry, i have edited the question.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/66963/23500) (and others).