# Prove that any postage greater than 17 can be made using 4 and 7 cent stamps

Tags: induction

Please use strong induction for the problem. I know that regular induction doesn't work. I assume there is a proof by logic by simply saying that 18, 19 and 20 cents can be made using these stamps and that you just need to subtract a 7 cent stamp and then add two four cent stamps to get the next higher cent value. However, that is not formaly strong induction.

Comment: For the general case (where the values may be different from 4 and 7), see for example [Largest integer that can't be represented as a non-negative combination](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66963/largest-integer-that-cant-be-represented-as-a-non-negative-linear-combination-o). Or google for the [Frobenius problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1**
$$18=7+7+4 \\
19=7+4+4+4\\
20=4+4+4+4+4 \\
21=7+7+7$$

**Hint 2:** If $n \geq 21$ and  you know that $P(1), P(2),.., P(n)$ is true, then $P(n-4)$ is true.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If you can make any four consecutive denominations you can make any afterward by adding four-cent stamps. So all you have to do is show combinations adding up to 18 to 21 cents.