# The largest positive integer which cannot be written in the form $5m + 3n$ where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers is?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, arithmetic

I came across this question and I was able to solve this question with the help of the options provided in the question and the answer turned out to be $15$. But it intrigued me to find a general statement for the solutions for these kind of problems.

How can we approach a general problem like "The largest positive integer which cannot be written in the form $Am + Bn$ where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers and $A$ and $B$ are positive integers too is?" Is there a general solution statement for this problem.

I looked up on the web and stumbled upon this statement from Frobenius:

> Suppose that  $gcd(a,b)=1$ . Then the largest integer  $k$  for which
> $am+bn=k$  has no non-negative integer solution  $(m,n)$  occurs when
> $k=ab−a−b$ .

The problem is when I apply this statement into my problem where $a=5$ and $b=3$ then it gives me the answer as $7$ which is less than what I got as answer.

Can someone please clarify this for me and give an idea to approach these kind of problems?

Thanks in advance !!!

PS : Just now I noticed that my answer 15 is basically $5*3$. So can we say that for our general problem statement i.e.  "The largest positive integer which cannot be written in the form $Am + Bn$ where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers and $A$ and $B$ are positive integers too is?", the answer will be $A*B$.

Comment: One difference is whether you want "positive" solutions or "non-negative" solutions.  You probably want $A$ and $B$ to be relatively prime.

Comment: umm...we can go for "positive" solutions and I am not sure of the conditions for $A$ and $B$. In my question they are relatively prime, but it would be interesting to know what if they are not. But for now we can stick with the relative prime condition.

Comment: Note than $n$ can be written as a linear combination of $3$ and $5$ with **nonnegative** integer coefficients if and only if $n+8$ can be written as a linear combination of $3$ and $5$ with **positive** integer coefficients. So, if $7$ is the answer to the one problem, then $15$ is the answer to the other problem.

Comment: Sounds like the [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem). This brings back memories of an [old Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNTSugyS038).

Comment: @bof : I did not get you here " So, if 7 is the answer to the one problem, then 15 is the answer to the other problem." Can you please tell me for what part the answer will be 7 and 15?

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66975/242) in the dupe explains how to shift the solution for $\,\,m,n\ge 1\,$ to $\,m,n\ge c,\,$ for any $c\ \ $

Comment: @Ganit The answers $15$ and $7$ are from the first and third paragraphs of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially repeating the comments:

Let $S(m, n)$ be the set of all $am + bn$ with $a, b \geq 0$.
Let $S_+(m, n)$ be the set of all $am + bn$ with $a, b > 0$.
Then there is a bijection $S(m, n) \to S_+(m, n)$ defined by $x \mapsto x+m+n$, since $(am + bn) + m + n = (a + 1)m + (b + 1)n$ and $a, b \geq 0$ iff $a+1, b+1 > 0$.
Therefore $\max S_+(m, n)^c = \max S(m, n)^c + m + n$,
and, by Frobenius, this is $mn$ provided $\gcd(m,n) = 1$.

Actually, the statement $\max S_+(m, n)^c = mn$ is a little more memorable than the usual statement $\max S(m, n)^c = mn - m - n$.

Comment: Can you please clarify one doubt for me? In which case the answer will turn out to be 7 and in which case the answer will be 15 as it came for porblem? I am getting confused here with two formulae $mn$ and $mn-m-n$.

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong , I went through this wikipedia page on coin problem and studied it and as I am not a full time mathematics student I might have understood it wrong but what i inferred that for the condition where m and n are non-negative integers, then in this scenario we have the formula of $\max S(m, n)^c = mn - m - n$ and when m and n are positive integers then we have $\max S_+(m, n)^c = mn$.

Comment: Yes $\max S(m, n)^c = mn - m - n$ and $S_+(m, n)^c = mn$.